# How can I run my own .py automatically on Django

Tags: python, django

i'm working on my first Django project and I would like to know how can I set my scraper to run automatically every hour or so to update the data on my site. I'm still in development environment and to update the database I'm running it manually, but that's a key feature of my project. Any help please...

Comment: linux = cron , windows = schedule task, python = crontab https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/

Comment: You may want to write a custom management command (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) and execute it from cron or schedule task as Mate mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks you very much guys!!!